# CSV SPLITTER script

Tags: powershell

asking your assistance, below my script was running correctly using powershell, my concern is when i run the script, the file inside becomes truncated digits in csv (Main file ex: field UniqueID: 004012306290015352) the data output when i run my script will shown 004012306290015350. Which means the final digits is not captured correctly, instead of "2" because the last digit from main file but it will become "0". which is wrong. all splitted files was affected the last digits.

please help me to resolve this, is this because of my script?

function Split-Csv {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$FilePath,
[Parameter()]
[string]$Delimiter = '|',
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$TargetFolder,
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[int]$NumberOfFiles
)

```
try {
    if (-not (Test-Path $TargetFolder)) {
        New-Item -Path $TargetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }

    $csvData = Import-Csv -Path $FilePath -Delimiter $Delimiter

    $startRow = 0

    $numberOfRowsPerFile = [Math]::Ceiling($csvData.Count / $NumberOfFiles)

    $counterRegular = 1
    $counterVoid = 1
    $counterReturn = 1

    while ($startRow -lt $csvData.Count) {
        $rowBatch = $csvData | Select-Object -Skip $startRow -First $numberOfRowsPerFile

        $eisUniqueId = $rowBatch.EisUniqueId -replace '\D', '' | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring([Math]::Max(0, $_.Length - 3)) }
        $ptunum = $rowBatch.Ptunum -replace '\D', '' | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring([Math]::Max(0, $_.Length - 5)) }
        $issueDtm = $rowBatch.IssueDtm
        $currentTimestamp = (Get-Date).ToString('HHmm')

        $fileType = ""
        if ($rowBatch.DocType -eq "01" -and [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($rowBatch.CorrectionCd)) {
            $fileType = "Regular"
            $counter = $counterRegular
            $counterRegular++
        }
        elseif ($rowBatch.DocType -eq "06" -and $rowBatch.CorrectionCd -eq "04") {
            $fileType = "Void"
            $counter = $counterVoid
            $counterVoid++
        }
        elseif ($rowBatch.DocType -eq "06" -and $rowBatch.CorrectionCd -eq "05") {
            $fileType = "Return"
            $counter = $counterReturn
            $counterReturn++
        }

        if ($fileType) {
            $fileName = '{0}{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5:D4}.csv' -f $eisUniqueId, $ptunum, $issueDtm, $currentTimestamp, $fileType, $counter
            $rowBatch | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path $TargetFolder $fileName) -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
        }

        $startRow += $numberOfRowsPerFile
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```

}

Split-Csv -FilePath "D:\Output\EIS_BIR.csv" -Delimiter '|' -TargetFolder "D:\Output" -NumberOfFiles 10000000

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue resides within this line:

```
$eisUniqueId = $rowBatch.EisUniqueId -replace '\D', '' | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring([Math]::Max(0, $_.Length - 3)) }
```

What this line is accomplishing is replacing all non-digit characters alongside an empty string, then selecting the last 3 digits of the outcome.

In other words, if the EisUniqueId is '004012306290015352', this line would yield '352', not '004012306290015352'.

This appears to be performed to format the output filename. If you wish to encompass the full EisUniqueId within the output filename, you should eliminate the -replace '\D', '' and Substring() operations.

Thus the line should be:

```
$eisUniqueId = $rowBatch.EisUniqueId
```

You have the identical operation utilized on the Ptunum field. Please adjust that line as well if you desire the full value:

```
$ptunum = $rowBatch.Ptunum
```

Afterwards, the script should accurately use the complete EisUniqueId and Ptunum values within the filename. This should not influence how the data within the CSV files themselves are handled. If the truncation issue is happening within the CSV data itself, then we might need to examine the other segments of your script. However, based on what you have disclosed, it appears like the filename formatting is the root cause.

Comment: I tried to change the $eisUniqueId = $rowBatch.EisUniqueId into another field available, but still the 004012306290015352 or this number truncated in csv, the output after run script that the last digit turn to "0" or 004012306290015350 which is not captured correctly from the main file that suppost to be "352" not "350", I have 5000 splitted files all are same output not accurate. is this because of being truncated and happens when converted into csv?

Comment: Good analysis, though eliminating `-replace '\D', ''` is probably not called for, assuming that only _digits_ should make up the ID. @SonnyRealJr, your symptom is a bit of a mystery and not explained by your code. Please consider updating your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
daniya shyanne!

All eight of your answers here since you joined 3 days ago appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.